# WPF and background worker and the calling thread must be STA

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I've implemented the solution from Stack Overflow question *[Implement progressbar in this simple WPF application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21076203)*.

MainWindow has its own viewmodel. Inside that viewmodel I receive the user's input and consume the WCF service using a background worker. After WCF serves the data back, I'm trying to display it in a new window. This is where the error occurs:

> The calling thread must be STA, because many UI components require
>   this.

I tried to put the `[STAThread]` attribute on the MainWindow [code-behind](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/code-behind) as well as inside the MainWindowViewModel contructor. In both cases nothing changed.

What am I missing?

**Update**
After user clicks command in viewmodel call LoadData method

```
private void LoadData(string searchBy)
{
    IsBusy = true;
    BackgroundWorker worker = new BackgroundWorker();
    worker.DoWork += (o, ea) =>
    {
        switch (searchBy)
        {
            // WCF call to load data
        }
    }

    worker.RunWorkerCompleted += (o, ea) =>
    {
       IsBusy = false;
    };

    worker.RunWorkerAsync();
```

Comment: Where are you creating the `BackgroundWorker`?

Comment: the "calling thread" in the message is not your UI thread. It is the WCF callback thread. You need to marshal the call from that background thread to your UI thread using Dispatcher, SynchronizationContext etc.

Comment: @Douglas I'm creating BackgroundWorker after button click to load data using wcf call.

Comment: @KaiWang can you pleae post concrete code.

Comment: possible duplicate of ["The calling thread must be STA, because many UI components require this" error when creating a WPF pop-up Window in thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2657212/the-calling-thread-must-be-sta-because-many-ui-components-require-this-error)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are numerous duplicates of this issue on Stack Overflow. For example, [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2657212/the-calling-thread-must-be-sta-because-many-ui-components-require-this-error).

Bottom line - any time you create UI components, you must use a single-threaded apartment (STA) thread. Background workers are not STA.  Therefore, you cannot create UI components in background workers. You cannot update UI components from background workers. Background workers are designed to run *in the background* (big surprise there), possibly to crunch data and return a result later on.

Comment: So, when background worker needs some user interaction, there is no way to get it?

Comment: A background worker by definition does not require user interaction. You have a logical problem with your design that needs to be resolved.

Answer (score 4):

I think you need to use `Application.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(action)`. This is to update the UI from a background thread.